# How to show that $f(x) \leq 1$ on $x > 0$?

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $$f(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}-2x}{e^x+e^{-x}-2}.$$

How do I show that $f(x) \leq 1$ for $x > 0$? We know that $f(x) \to 1$ so I tried showing that $f'$ is positive but this is too hard to show.

Comment: If $b > 0$, then $\frac{a}{b} \leqslant 1 \iff a \leqslant b$.

Comment: But the denominator is only positive when $x$ is big enough.

Comment: Take another look. $x$ need not be large.

Comment: Don't know if it's helpful, but note that this expression is $$\frac1{(\log(\sinh x - x))'}$$ so if you can show that $(\log(\sinh x - x))'\geq 1$ you would be done

Comment: $e^0+e^{-0} = 2$

Comment: Thanks all. @MPW thanks but I think that is much harder!

Answer (score 3):

The denominator is $e^x+e^{-x}-2=(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})^2>0$ for $x\ne0$ so that we only need to verify that 
$$e^x-e^{-x}-2x\le  e^x+e^{-x}-2$$
or equivalently that
$$ e^{-x}\ge 1-x$$
And this is true because it compares the (convex) exponential function with its tangent at $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the denominator is $e^x+e^{-x}-2=(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})^2>0$, for $x\ne 0$, we need to show that 
$$e^x-e^{-x}-2x\le  e^x+e^{-x}-2$$
or equivalently we need to show that
$$ 2e^{-x}+2x-2 \ge0.$$
Define $$g(x)= e^{-x}+x-1, $$
then, by taking its derivative, it is easy to show that this function is strictly increasing in $(0, +\infty)$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

So this won't negate anything already said, I just can't write comments yet, and I feel it's worth illustrating.

Lets write $f$ out a different way

$f(x)= \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}-2x}{e^{x}+e^{-x}-2} = \frac{\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}-x}{\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}-1} = \frac{sinh(x)-x}{cosh(x)-1}$

So I don't know how familiar you are with the expression, but $tanh$ is generally a hyperbolic function sitting between -1 and 1, and the conclusion is pretty much a given. Obviously you can multiply that boundary up or down, but here quickly check that the expression above is less than the denominator, as the comments stated. There's no essential need to write it out as hyperbolic functions, but why not! Here's my take on the answer

Check $-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}-x\leq \frac{e^{-x}}{2}-1 \Leftrightarrow 1 \leq e^{-x}+x$
But $e^{-x}$ decreases slower than the linearly decreasing function $\mid-x+1\mid$, and the situation is clearly true if we take $1 \leq \ \mid-x+1\mid+x$. Hence the conclusion follows